# Two ways to do temporal join,which one is preferred

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#processing-time-temporal-join,

It is using the grammar `JOIN ... FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` to do temporal join ,like the following does

```
SELECT
  o.amount, o.currency, r.rate, o.amount * r.rate
FROM
  Orders AS o
  JOIN LatestRates FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF o.proctime AS r
  ON r.currency = o.currency
```

There is also another way to do `temporal join` , that is using `TemporalTableFunction`

```
        val latestRates = rateTable.createTemporalTableFunction("ps", "currency");
        tableEnv.registerFunction("LatestRates ", latestRates );

        val result = tableEnv
                .sqlQuery("""select o.amount, o.currency, r.rate, o.amount * r.rate from  Orders as o Lateral table (LatestRates (o.ps)) d  where o.currency =d.currency""");
```

I would ask which one is preferred, it looks to me the first one is preferred, since it is following SQL standard to express Temporal table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach, using `JOIN ... FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` is the preferred approach. `Table#createTemporalTableFunction(...)` was deprecated when this better approach was added in Flink 1.12 (see [FLIP-132 Temporal Table DDL and Temporal Table Join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/kiV4CQ) for details).

Comment: Note, to do a processing time join, this is not quite correct and has been clarified in the documents of newer versions: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#processing-time-temporal-join Here it seems *you do* still need to use a temporal table function to get the latest value in a versioned table.  See also here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23313